# Finding an ideal linear transformation in 2D

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, linear-transformations

Assume that I have a collection of $n$ points $\mathcal{X}=\{(x_1,y_1),...,(x_n,y_n)\}$ in some two-dimensional space $\mathbb{R^2}$. It is my goal to transform these points through a linear transformation $f$ (with operations like translation, scaling, rotation, homothety, etc.) in order to fit a requirement as well as possible. In my case, this requirement is that one coordinate of each of the transformed points is known, the other coordinate can be chosen freely (see figure below).

Now it is clear that depending on the target coordinates $\{u_1,...,u_n\}$ no perfect map fitting my requirements may exist. In other cases, there might be infinitely many plausible maps.

**Hence my question**: is there a good approach with which I can find the best linear transformation (e.g., in terms of least-squares deviation between the mapped and prescribed $u$ coordinates)? I could possibly find an iterative brute-force solution, but I would like to know if there exists a more elegant solution.

[image]

Comment: Beware that you're asking a bad question: you ask for "the best", linear transformation (by which you appear to mean "affine transformation) but even in your example, if $T(x, y)$ is an optimal solution, then so is $S(x, y) = T(x, y) + (0, 1)$, i.e., the "best" is not unique. It's **a** best transformation. If you try to carry out @user618894's approach, you'll tend to find the solution is underdetermined, so a companion matrix will be not-full-rank, and therefore non-invertible. I mention this practical point to emphasize that my comment is not mere pedantry. Pedantry maybe, but not 'mere.'

Comment: I understood his question as if for some points he has the x and for others he has the y, so there might not be the ambiguity that concerns you.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. John Hughes is indeed correct - my question wasn't phrased very well. If I find one perfect fit, then I will have infinitely many solutions by translation along the v dimension (I was aware of this, hence my reference to infinitely many possible solutions in the second paragraph; the title didn't reflect this, though).

Comment: A bit of background: this non-uniqueness is indeed part of my motivation for this question. What my example represents are points in the $xy$ plane with a certain potential $u$. I want to find all possible potential fields which fit the observations in the $xy$ plane. So I figured if I find the linear transformation from 2D physical space into the 2D equipotential/pathline space, I could invert the transformation to find all possible potential fields which might explain the point-wise data I have in the $xy$-plane.

Comment: a reasonable approach, given the ambiguity, is to say "...and I want $S(x_1, y_1)$ to have $y$-coordinate $0$". That adds a row to your matrix, makes it full rank (except in rare circumstances where there's a ton of symmetry) and lets you solve it uniquely; then you can translate the solution up and down at will.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to define $P_i=\begin{bmatrix}x_i\\y_i\\1 \end{bmatrix}$, then the most general affine transformation is parametrized by and augmented matrix
$P_{i,transformed}=\begin{bmatrix} a&&b&&c\\d&&e&&f\\0&&0&&1\end{bmatrix}P_i $ and writing a least squares fit for the 6 parameters $a,b,c,d,e,f$ becomes standard.